# What's the kernel of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the kernel of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\  4 & 5 &
> 6\\  7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix}.$

I will try to keep it short and write what else is known. $\det(A)=0$ thus kernel exists. Then I have written:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\  4 & 5 &
6\\  7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

(Don't check, this will be correct too:)

$I: x+2y+3z=0$

$II: y+2z=0 \Leftrightarrow y=-2z$, insert that in $I$

$x-z=0 \Leftrightarrow x=z$

Here comes the part I wasn't sure about:

$$\ker(A) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
z\\ 
-2z\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} \mid z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

---

Is it correct like that?

Comment: Yes. You could also put $ker(A) = span\{ (1,-2,1) \}$.

Comment: @d.t. Oh thanks that's good to know

Comment: @tenepolis just for your interest: the kernel always exists, since the zerovector will always be in the kernel. Hence you don't need to compute the determinant! (well, unless you would have found that $\det(A) \neq 0$, in which case you know only the zerovector satisfies $Ax = 0$, but this is the only thing you could derive from the determinant). As one of the answers show, rowreducing your matrix and checking for zerorows is the way to go.

Comment: @Student If I was asked to determine the basis of kernel, could I just take the nullvector to save time?

Comment: @tenepolis no, a basis should span the space. I just pointed out that you don't need to compute the determinant since it will only give you information if it is nonzero. So you save you time, you can omit this. Moreover, you seemed to make the reasoning that the kernel exists since the determinant is zero, but the kernel always exists! That was what my comment said, nothing less, nothing more :)

Comment: The kernel always exists since $A0=0$. I suspect that you meant that since $\det A=0$ that the kernel is *nontrivial*.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you just rank the matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\4 & 5 & 6\\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}$--->$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

And then find the connection between  $x, y$  and  $z$ and extract any unnecessary factor.

Comment: Once you’ve gotten that far, you can read a basis for the kernel directly from the reduced matrix.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to post a comment)

To add to the previous answers `Ker(A)=N(A)` (`null space` of `A`). So if you compute the `null space` of the matrix you will end up having the span of `null space` as 
$$N(A) = span(\begin{bmatrix} 
1
\\-2
\\1
\end{bmatrix} )
$$